# How to store a pairs of key and value, and add them dynamically using action? Map cause 'detected unserializable state' error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

I want to store some data in the state. The problem is that I have to add it one by one dynamically dispatching an action. I tried two solutions: `Record<string, number>` and `Map<string, number>`.

Record is thrwoing an error in the reducer method that says the object is not extensible.

With Map I have a different problem: `Detected unserializable state at "airplanes.aircraftRotation"`

Maybe I did something wrong while implementing these methods:

```
export interface State extends EntityState<Airplane> {
  error?: any;
  aircraftRotation: Map<string, number>;
}

export const initialState: State = airplanesAdapter.getInitialState({
  error: null,
  aircraftRotation: new Map<string, number>(),
});

export default State;
```

And the reducer:

```
function updateAircraftRotation(state: State, aircraftCallSing: string, rotation: number): State {
  state.aircraftRotation.set(aircraftCallSing, rotation);
  return state;
}
```

Can someone give me some hint how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

A `Map` is not a fully serializable value, and so RTK will always warn about this.

The better approach here is to use a plain JS object instead, especially since your `Map` just has string keys.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not returning your store in the reducer properly. As your are using a Map object which might not be immutable/serializable., this might cause issues as raised here.

[When ngrx store state contains a Map, why are changes to this Map not recognized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47609484/when-ngrx-store-state-contains-a-map-why-are-changes-to-this-map-not-recognized)

you might want to try something like this in your reducer. Where you "clone" the Map, and the new copy will allow the data to be serializable?

```
function updateAircraftRotation(state: State, aircraftCallSing: string, rotation: number): State {
let aircraftRotation =   new Map(state.aircraftRotation)

aircraftRotation.set(aircraftCallSing, rotation);
  return {...state,aircraftRotation } ;
}
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is here - I think the problem is using Map type itself. I'm keep getting the same error with your changes unfortunatelly.

Answer (score 0):

It's a [best practice](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions) that you should not store any data in Redux if it is not serializable.  A `Map` object is not serializable because it has instance methods such as `set()` which will be lost if converting to and from JSON.

The TypeScript type `Record<string, number>` describes any object with `string` keys and `number` values. This is the correct type to use, but you'll want to implement it with a plain object instead of your `new Map<string, number>()`.

The initial value would just be an empty object `{}`.

```
export interface State extends EntityState<Airplane> {
  error?: any;
  aircraftRotation: Record<string, number>;
}

export const initialState: State = airplanesAdapter.getInitialState({
  error: null,
  aircraftRotation: {},
});
```

In your reducer, you no longer have the `set` method from the `Map` so you will need to update your object differently.

I'm confused by your reducer code as I'm seeing two arbitrary arguments and no `action`.

You'll probably need to return a new object which copies all of the properties of the previous, like this:

```
return {
   ...state,
   aircraftRotation: {
      ...state.aircraftRotation,
      [aircraftCallSing]: rotation
   }
}
```

With immutability middleware (Redux Toolkit), you can just set the property directly, like this:

```
state.aircraftRotation[aircraftCallSing] = rotation;
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgUQHY2DAngZRgQxgFMAaOAYyiMKLQ2wEEATfMYqOAXzgDMoIQcAOQABVAHMoADwD0RdJixCAsAChQkWIgpUaOADbBypOAAV8WfRHxMG5DBFRde-QaKpMArlIBWAZxkYCAh9AGtMFVU1YHQiKB58YzgGYCgwfXxUIkQ1ODy4YCYALjg-GCgY8QBuXPyQCCYifRKyioka1U41NXJHMrh8VPTMoj9mVnY4AF4damI6RXG2OIAeFLSMrIA+AAoASm7VIilNeBj2BKS8Gjhj4lQmPxQFbGviNaHNoi2c1XzbqD8KAAfhKmSwHX+gyglHwPBgACUIAQHKgSgiiL0oEwVq1KmRUJ4QAAjOJbDpdKJHE7QeC9VD9GKYYD4fRvIgldnTAafEZjFjLKAAOnERBgAElUMzWeydghank4kCSoT9PoSAqeTCoHDEcjCMBHCUEJwNZ09h0en14NDhlk-AYjNkZpQ5kRHcY5ZrUPgQBzhLavn4hGb-kyMDKUf7wyy2VHQ-kPJ5jFA-MbNf9PGAWMR1rD4UiUYbUDsyjQyIlUSVzJZrLZ7MWVkhofmYABhVlsyotcqVKpwfhFo1wQkkuJcLZ7X7-Gf5en9ZupVsdtU4fED-Wo5wzSvFoVgCxWGyQ2czmQyOAgTxRuAwAAW2TLxDITEcQngVBgnigTnB98qQoZqeT5EEKLY6gWm7FgA2uBuorl2EgALrcoOBqOCes6mpq2HmocxynBQ1raFmOZEHmEF6kOTjcDuvL2h6oG7n0VRAA)